# Polymorphic parameters javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, polymorphism

I am trying to imitate the jQuery `animate()` method to strip out the `opacity` style for unsupported browsers (Internet Explorer of course)!

However, I am struggling to imitate the parameters that the jQuery `animate()` method accepts.

According to the jQuery documentation:

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
.animate( properties, options )
```

What I would like to know is how does the function know whether parameter 2 is the duration or the options...?

Notice the three arguments here:

```
$('#test').animate({opacity:0},200,function(){
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

But I can also execute the same function like this (notice the easing parameter):

```
$('#test').animate({opacity:0},200,'swing',function(){
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

How does the function know that the third parameter is a string, not a function?

**Surely this is not done like so????**

```
if(typeof parameter1=='string'){
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Had you considered they might count the `arguments` and do it that way? Also, why not just look at the jQuery source to find out?

Comment: @Jamiec counting alone wouldn't work, as its perfectly valid to pass 2 parameters to both signatures. Some variable type sniffing is required.

Comment: @Jamiec I have looked at the jQuery source and it wasnt too helpful, couldnt really find what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely this is not done like so????
>
> ```
> if(typeof parameter1=='string'){
>     // and so on
> }
> ```

Yes, that is exactly how it is done.

---

From the jQuery source:

```
var opt = speed && typeof speed === "object" ? jQuery.extend({},
speed) : {
    complete: fn || !fn && easing || jQuery.isFunction(speed) && speed,
    duration: speed,
    easing: fn && easing || easing && !jQuery.isFunction(easing) && easing
};

opt.duration = jQuery.fx.off ? 0 : typeof opt.duration === "number" ? opt.duration : opt.duration in jQuery.fx.speeds ? jQuery.fx.speeds[opt.duration] : jQuery.fx.speeds._default;
```

Can be rewritten to be more readable this way:

```
var opt = { };

if (typeof speed == 'object')
    opt = jQuery.extend({ }, speed);
else {

    if (fn)
        opt.complete = fn;
    else if (easing)
        opt.complete = easing;
    else if (jQuery.isFunction(speed))
        opt.complete = speed;

    opt.duration = speed;

    if (fn && easing)
        opt.easing = easing;
    else if (easing && !jQuery.isFunction(easing))
        opt.easing = easing;

}

if (jQuery.fx.off)
    opt.duration = 0;
else if (typeof opt.duration === 'number')
    opt.duration = opt.duration;
else if (opt.duration in jQuery.fx.speeds)
    opt.duration = jQuery.fx.speeds[opt.duration];
else
    opt.duration = jQuery.fx.speeds._default;
```

---

### Update

If you want an easier way to take care of this logic for you, [candy](https://github.com/Nathan-Wall/candy/blob/master/releases/1.0.5/candy.js) provides a neat Array helper called `persuade`. This function allows you to pass in an array (or `arguments`) object with a list of types. You will be returned an array with the arguments organized by the types. It's an easy way to deal with polymorphic parameters:

```
function foo(/* duration, easing, complete */) {
    var args = candy.Arrays.persuade(arguments, [ 'number', 'string', 'function' ]);
    var duration = args[0], easing = args[1], complete = args[2];
    console.log(duration, easing, complete);
}

foo('test');
// => undefined, 'test', undefined

foo(2, function() { });
// => 2, undefined, function() { }
```

Comment: Thought it might be something more creative, oh well. Thank you

Comment: Updated with an easier method for accomplishing your task.

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to know is how does the function know whether parameter 2 is the duration or the options...?

If the 2nd parameter is an object, then it's the options. If it can be parsed to an `int` it's the `duration`. If it's a function, it's the `callback`, otherwise it's the `easing`.

Comment: So it is basically just a list of if statements as I suggested?

Comment: @BenCarey effectively yes. Here's the relevant source of jQuery which does it: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.speed

Comment: Didnt realise it would be so easy, thought it would be something fancy :-)